# JQuery Coding - Multiple Links slideToggle 1 div tag and different content

Tags: jquery

I'm seeking help with a JQuery coding issue.

What it is:  I have 8 links in a `<ul>` horizontal row.  Below those links I have a `<div>` that will display the content of each link.

Example:
L = Link
DDD...= Div

```
                L     L     L     L
                L     L     L     L

                DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

Coding Help:  I'm newer to JQuery and I don't know if I'm searching for the right coding...but what I want to do is have each link call upon the 1 div tag and display the different content for each link.  This DIV tag is also a slideToggle

Current JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("ul.columns li img").click(function(){
            $("#pressed").slideToggle("fast");
        });
        $('#pressed').hide();

    });
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerimg"><img src="#" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middlecolumn">
        <ul class="columns">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>News</h2>
                    <p>What is going on in the World</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>News</h2>
                    <p>What is going on in the World</p>
                </div>
            </li>
                    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="panel">
        <div id="pressed">Check this out!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show your html as well?

Comment: Just t orepeat David and empower his request: I can imagine your method working with the also imagined HTML. Post your HTML to find the difference!

Comment: I have inserted the HTML, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

definitivly needs more code from your side, but i think i understood.
something like that?

```
function swichDiv(link){
    $("#pressed").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#pressed").html('<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="'+link+'"/>')    
    $("#pressed").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

UNTESTED, will update after more info... but that MIGHT do it (can also store info in array and do it according to URL of img or something like that.)

Comment: It did not work but I believe I did not integrate it right with the HTML?  I see what you are doing but it could be on my end not fully understanding.